# Blank screen when generating point cloud from image with Open3D

Tags: python, point-clouds, open3d

So I tried creating a point cloud with the Open3D library in python and in the end, it's basically just the 2 lines as referenced in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60648588/can-open3d-visualize-a-point-cloud-in-rgb-mode), **but when I run my code (see below) all I get is a white screen popping up.** I've ran it in Jupyter notebook, but running it in a python script from console didn't change anything nor it threw an error.
I should mention that I created the images in Blender and saved it as OpenExr, meaning that the depth value range between 0 and 4 (I've truncated it to 4 for the background). You can see that they are proper images below and I could also transform them to Open3D pictures and display them without problems.

**Edit (27-03-2020): Added complete minimal example**

```
import OpenEXR
import numpy as np
import array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import open3d as o3d
%matplotlib inline

exr_img = OpenEXR.InputFile('frame0100.exr')

depth_img = array.array('f', exr_img.channel('View Layer.Depth.Z'))
r_img = array.array('f', exr_img.channel('View Layer.Combined.R'))
g_img = array.array('f', exr_img.channel('View Layer.Combined.G'))
b_img = array.array('f', exr_img.channel('View Layer.Combined.B'))

def reshape_img(img):
    return np.array(img).reshape(720, 1280)

img_array = np.dstack((reshape_img(r_img),
                     reshape_img(g_img),
                     reshape_img(b_img),
                     reshape_img(depth_img)))

#Background returns very large value, truncate it to 4
img_array[img_array == 10000000000.0] = 4

colour = o3d.geometry.Image(np.array(img_array[:, :, :3]))
depth = o3d.geometry.Image(np.array(img_array[:, :, 3]*1000).astype('uint16'))
o3d.draw_geometries([depth])

pinhole_cam = o3d.open3d.camera.PinholeCameraIntrinsic(width= 1280, height=720, cx=640,cy=360,fx=500,fy=500)

rgbd = o3d.create_rgbd_image_from_color_and_depth(colour, depth, convert_rgb_to_intensity = False, depth_scale=1000)
pcd = o3d.create_point_cloud_from_rgbd_image(rgbd, pinhole_cam)

o3d.draw_geometries([pcd])
```

*Please overlook the hacky way of importing the data, as I am new to Open3D and produced the data myself, I did it step-by-step for checks and for confirming the data integrity*

[image: The picture I tried to use with some statistics]

**I assume it might have to do with my parameters for the pinhole camera.** Tbh, I have no idea what would be the proper parameters except that cy, cy should be the centre of the image and fx, fy should be *sensible*. As my depth values are in Blender metres but Open3D apparently expects millimetres, the scaling should make sense.

I'd appreciate it if you could give me any help debugging it. But if you were to point me in the direction of a better working library to create 3D point clouds from images I wouldn't mind either. The documentation I found with Open3D is lacking at best.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, **Open3D expects your 3-channel color image to be of `uint8` type**.

Otherwise, it would return an empty point cloud, resulting in the blank window you see.

---

**Update 2020-3-27, late night in my time zone:)**

*Now that you have provided your code, let's dive in!*

*From your function names, I guess you are using Open3D `0.7.0` or something like that. The code I provided is in `0.9.0`. Some function names changed and [new functionality](http://www.open3d.org/index.php/2019/12/19/open3d-0-9-0-is-ready/) added in.*

*When I run your code in `0.9.0` (after some minor modifications of course), there's a **RuntimeError**:*

```
RuntimeError: [Open3D ERROR] [CreatePointCloudFromRGBDImage] Unsupported image format.
```

---

And we can see from the Open3D `0.9.0` [source](https://github.com/intel-isl/Open3D/blob/master/src/Open3D/Geometry/PointCloudFactory.cpp#L175) that your color image must be of **3 channels and take only 1 byte each** (uint8) or **be of 1 channel and take 4 bytes** (float, that means intensity image):

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<PointCloud> PointCloud::CreateFromRGBDImage(
        const RGBDImage &image,
        const camera::PinholeCameraIntrinsic &intrinsic,
        const Eigen::Matrix4d &extrinsic /* = Eigen::Matrix4d::Identity()*/,
        bool project_valid_depth_only) {
    if (image.depth_.num_of_channels_ == 1 &&
        image.depth_.bytes_per_channel_ == 4) {
        if (image.color_.bytes_per_channel_ == 1 &&
            image.color_.num_of_channels_ == 3) {
            return CreatePointCloudFromRGBDImageT<uint8_t, 3>(
                    image, intrinsic, extrinsic, project_valid_depth_only);
        } else if (image.color_.bytes_per_channel_ == 4 &&
                   image.color_.num_of_channels_ == 1) {
            return CreatePointCloudFromRGBDImageT<float, 1>(
                    image, intrinsic, extrinsic, project_valid_depth_only);
        }
    }
    utility::LogError(
            "[CreatePointCloudFromRGBDImage] Unsupported image format.");
    return std::make_shared<PointCloud>();
}
```

Otherwise, there'll be errors like I encountered.
***However***, in the version of `0.7.0`, the [source code](https://github.com/intel-isl/Open3D/blob/v0.7.0/src/Open3D/Geometry/PointCloudFactory.cpp#L143) is:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<PointCloud> CreatePointCloudFromRGBDImage(
        const RGBDImage &image,
        const camera::PinholeCameraIntrinsic &intrinsic,
        const Eigen::Matrix4d &extrinsic /* = Eigen::Matrix4d::Identity()*/) {
    if (image.depth_.num_of_channels_ == 1 &&
        image.depth_.bytes_per_channel_ == 4) {
        if (image.color_.bytes_per_channel_ == 1 &&
            image.color_.num_of_channels_ == 3) {
            return CreatePointCloudFromRGBDImageT<uint8_t, 3>(image, intrinsic,
                                                              extrinsic);
        } else if (image.color_.bytes_per_channel_ == 4 &&
                   image.color_.num_of_channels_ == 1) {
            return CreatePointCloudFromRGBDImageT<float, 1>(image, intrinsic,
                                                            extrinsic);
        }
    }   
    utility::PrintDebug(
            "[CreatePointCloudFromRGBDImage] Unsupported image format.\n");
    return std::make_shared<PointCloud>();
}
```

*That means Open3D still does not support it, but it would only warn you. And only in debug mode!

After that, it will return an **empty point cloud**. (Actually both versions do this.) That explains the blank window.*

Now you should know, you can make `convert_rgb_to_intensity=True` and succeed. Though you still should normalize your color image first.
Or you can convert the color image to be in range `[0, 255]` and of type `uint8`.
Both will work.

*Now I hope all is clear. Hooray!*

<sub>P.S. Actually I usually found Open3D source code to be easy to read. And if you know C++, you could read it whenever something like this happens.</sub>

---

**Update 2020-3-27:**

*I cannot reproduce your result and I don't know why it happened (you should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).*

*Using the image you provided in the comment, I wrote the following code and it works well. If it still doesn't work on your computer, maybe your Open3D is broken.*

*(I'm not familiar with .exr images, hence the data extraction might be ugly :)*

```py
import Imath
import array
import OpenEXR

import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d


# extract data from exr files
f = OpenEXR.InputFile('frame.exr')
FLOAT = Imath.PixelType(Imath.PixelType.FLOAT)
cs = list(f.header()['channels'].keys())  # channels
data = [np.array(array.array('f', f.channel(c, FLOAT))) for c in cs] 
data = [d.reshape(720, 1280) for d in data]
rgb = np.concatenate([data[i][:, :, np.newaxis] for i in [3, 2, 1]], axis=-1)
# rgb /= np.max(rgb)  # this will result in a much darker image
np.clip(rgb, 0, 1.0)  # to better visualize as HDR is not supported?

# get rgbd image
img = o3d.geometry.Image((rgb * 255).astype(np.uint8))
depth = o3d.geometry.Image((data[-1] * 1000).astype(np.uint16))
rgbd = o3d.geometry.RGBDImage.create_from_color_and_depth(img, depth, convert_rgb_to_intensity=False)

# some guessed intrinsics
intr = o3d.open3d.camera.PinholeCameraIntrinsic(1280, 720, fx=570, fy=570, cx=640, cy=360)

# get point cloud and visualize
pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud.create_from_rgbd_image(rgbd, intr)
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])
```

*And the result is:*

[image]

---

**Original answer:**

You have misunderstood the meaning of `depth_scale`.

Use this line:
`depth = o3d.geometry.Image(np.array(img_array[:, :, 3]*1000).astype('uint16'))`

---

The Open3D [documentation](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.geometry.RGBDImage.html#open3d.geometry.RGBDImage.create_from_color_and_depth) said *the depth values will first be scaled and then truncated*. Actually it means the pixel values in your depth image will first **divide this number** rather than multiply,  as you can see in the Open3D [source](https://github.com/intel-isl/Open3D/blob/master/src/Open3D/Geometry/Image.cpp#L106):

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<Image> Image::ConvertDepthToFloatImage(
        double depth_scale /* = 1000.0*/, double depth_trunc /* = 3.0*/) const {
    // don't need warning message about image type
    // as we call CreateFloatImage
    auto output = CreateFloatImage();
    for (int y = 0; y < output->height_; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < output->width_; x++) {
            float *p = output->PointerAt<float>(x, y);
            *p /= (float)depth_scale;
            if (*p >= depth_trunc) *p = 0.0f;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Actually we usually take it for granted that **values in depth images should be integers** (I guess that's why Open3D did not point that out clearly in their documentation), since floating-point images are less common.
You cannot store `1.34` meters in .png images, since they will lose precision. As a result, we store `1340` in depth images and later processes will first convert it back to `1.34`.

---

As for camera intrinsics for your depth image, I guess there'll be configuration parameters in Blender when you create it. I'm not familiar with Blender, so I'll not talk about it. **However, if you do not understand general camera intrinsics, you might want to take a look at [this](http://ksimek.github.io/2013/08/13/intrinsic/)**.

Comment: Actually, I did try the commented-out line first but to no avail. But is it right to assume the colour image should be in integers, too? As I saved both together in OpenExr format, it might face the same issue. But as I can display the iamge with open3d, I guess that might not be it. I guess I fiddle with the intrinsic values. As far as I understood it I then don't need the extrinsic values, right?

Comment: As I understand it, you don't need the extrinsics. Could you provide the depth images you're using?

Comment: @Megamind  Actually I did not mean that types are important (especially in Python). Type conversion is easy. I mean **values are important**. Open3D expects depth to be in millimeters when passed in `create_rgbd_image_from_color_and_depth` and you cannot pass depth in meters. The integer thing is for explaining why  `depth_scale` is divided rather than multiplied.

Comment: Also FYI, use `np.asarray(pcd.points)` to convert point cloud points into numpy arrays. Then you can verify its values and sizes.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xgW4vTCP42up7L8lE-iTc7b7nE-tMFlQ) is an equivalent file; it's not exactly the same, but was generated by the same process and produces the same "error" (or rather, blank screen). As I pointed out, I did use the uncommented line before to pass the depth in millimeters, it didn't help, though.

Comment: I've added the minimal example, I wonder if it's the clipping or casting the image to uint8. I'll try implementing your solution step-by-step. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**@Jing Zhaos's answer worked!** However, I assume his version of Open3D is different than mine, I had to change 2 function calls likes this (and changed the naming slightly):

```
exr_img = OpenEXR.InputFile('frame0100.exr')
cs = list(exr_img.header()['channels'].keys())  # channels
FLOAT = Imath.PixelType(Imath.PixelType.FLOAT)

img_data = [np.array(array.array('f', exr_img.channel(c, FLOAT))) for c in cs]
img_data = [d.reshape(720,1280) for d in img_data]

rgb = np.concatenate([img_data[i][:, :, np.newaxis] for i in [3, 2, 1]], axis=-1)
np.clip(rgb, 0, 1.0)  # to better visualize as HDR is not supported?


img = o3d.geometry.Image((rgb * 255).astype(np.uint8))
depth = o3d.geometry.Image((img_data[-1] * 1000).astype(np.uint16))
#####rgbd = o3d.geometry.RGBDImage.create_from_color_and_depth(img, depth, convert_rgb_to_intensity=False)

rgbd = o3d.create_rgbd_image_from_color_and_depth(img, depth, convert_rgb_to_intensity=False)


# some guessed intrinsics
intr = o3d.open3d.camera.PinholeCameraIntrinsic(1280, 720, fx=570, fy=570, cx=640, cy=360)

# get point cloud and visualize
#####pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud.create_from_rgbd_image(rgbd, intr)
pcd = o3d.create_point_cloud_from_rgbd_image(rgbd, intr)


o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])
```

otherwise I got following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'open3d.open3d.geometry.RGBDImage' has no attribute 'create_from_color_and_depth'
```

Hopefully that also helps others with my Python/Open3D version. Not quite sure where exactly the mistake in my code is, but I am satisfied to have usable code. **Thanks again to Jing Zhao!**

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain. And it turns out *my data extraction of exr* truly is ugly compared to yours :)

Comment: Well, I'm completely satisfied, thanks for taking the time! Also my extraction is a bit more explanatory, I considered yours preferable in most parts due to being shorter and in this way, more elegant.

Comment: I'm really happy to be of help! You're welcome and welcome to SO :)